# Paginating Api query in Ejs and Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, pagination, ejs

I'm new to Programming as a whole and I still don't understand the concept of Pagination. Currently if I make a call to the New york times api, my ejs page displays the first 10 results as returned by the api. My goal is to enable users to click on the next page, this click should call the next page of the api and display it for the users.

app.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});


app.post("/", function(req, res) {

const query = req.body.query;
var HeadT = req.body.query;
HeadT = HeadT.split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ');
const apikey = "";
var begin_date = req.body.begin_date;
begin_date = begin_date.replace(/-/g, "");
var end_date = req.body.end_date;
end_date = end_date.replace(/-/g, "");
var sort = req.body.sort;
sort = sort.toLowerCase();
var page = 0;
const url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?query=" + query + 
"&begin_date=" + begin_date + "&end_date=" + end_date + "&sort=" + sort + "&api-key=" + apikey + 
"&page=" + page;

const request = https.get(url, response => {
let body = [];
response.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
  var nydata = JSON.parse(body);
  nydata = nydata.response.docs;

  res.render('news_page', {
    nydata: nydata, HeadT: HeadT//, published:published
  });


     });
  });
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

news_page.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
  <!-- Icons -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images\logo.png">
  <title><%= HeadT %></title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Image and text -->
  <nav class="navbar ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="images\logo.png" class="logo">
      Home | <%= HeadT %> Related Articles
    </a>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <% for (var dat of nydata ){  %>
    <div class="row NewsGrid">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images\logo.png" alt="" class="rounded">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <a href="<%= dat.web_url %>">
          <h4><%= dat.headline.main %> </h4>
          <p><%= dat.lead_paragraph %> </p>
          <h6><%= dat.byline.original %> </h6>
          <h6><%= dat.multimedia.url %> </h6>
          <p> Published: <%= dat.pub_date.substring(0, 10)%> </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>

  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul name="page" class="pagination justify-content-center">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

index.ejs code

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
  <!-- Icons -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images\logo.png">
  <title>Company</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="masthead">
    <div class="masthead-bg"></div>
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-12 my-auto">
          <div class="masthead-content text-white py-5 py-md-0">
            <h1 class="mb-3">Find Company Articles!</h1>
            <p class="mb-5">We know how hard it is to find articles of specific companies, so we thought it'll be good idea to make it easy for you. Happy Searching!.
            </p>
            <form role="form" action="/" method="post" class="registration-form">
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" placeholder="Company Name" aria-label="Company Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" id="start" name="begin_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" id="start" name="end_date" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sub">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <select id="inputState" name="sort"class="form-control">
                      <option selected>Newest</option>
                      <option>Oldest</option>
                      <option>Relevance</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" value="Search">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Node code

```
    app.post("/", function(req, res) {
      const {query} = req.body;
      const HeadT = body.query.split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ');
      const apikey = "";
      const begin_date = body.begin_date.replace(/-/g, "");
      const end_date = body.end_date.replace(/-/g, "");
      const sort = body.sort.toLowerCase();
      const page = body.page || '1';
      const url = new Url("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json");
      const params = new URLSearchParams(;
      params.set("api-key", apikey);
      params.set("query", query);
      params.set("begin_date", begin_date);
      params.set("end_date", end_date);
      params.set("sort", sort);
      params.set("page", page);


      const request = fetch(`${url}?${params.toString()}`)
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( docs => {
         res.render('news_page', {
            nydata: json.response.docs, HeadT: HeadT, page: page
          });
      })
    });
```

As I dont have access to nytimes API, I cannot know how pagination works on it, but in nydata, you should set the maxPage, value that comes from API (normally).

Try calling this method with needed needed params and page=1 then page=2.

Now you can change the ejb code to display a pagination with currentPage = page and maxPage.

On click, you just have to make a call with `page=XX` where XX is the button clicked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I’m still struggling with setting up the api call from the front end to the backend. I want the user’s click to call the next page of the api but I’m drawing a blank